# How to update message of dataflows in Nifi Registry?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

In the progress of upgrading Nifi-1.10.0 from Nifi-1.9.2,'flow.xml.gz' is copied to new app.However,the files storaged in registry are unchanaged.
as following message:

```
$ cat 4.snapshot | grep 'version' 
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
              "version" : "1.9.2"
```

How to update them to show 'version:1.10.0'?there is a way to commit group in Nifi-1.10.0 but TOO TROUBLE!ANY OTHER SUGGESTION?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The version fields in registry will get updated the next time you save a new version of those flows. It doesn't cause any issues for the versions to remain as 1.9.2, those flows can still be imported and used in 1.10.0.